# How do I prevent empty properties being sent - object.assign

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search feature in Angular. I assign the params to an object using object.assign. However not all the fields are required. If an empty field is there, its sent up as an empty string.

How do I assign only properties that have a value.

```
export class PropertySearchComponent implements OnInit {

searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchParams: any = {};
  properties: Property;

  constructor(private advertService: AdvertService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createSearchForm();
  }

  createSearchForm() {
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      county: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      town: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_bedrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_bedrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_bathrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_bathrooms: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      min_price: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      max_price: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      selling_type: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
      property_type: ['', Validators.nullValidator],
    });
  }

  search() {
    this.searchParams = (Object.assign({}, this.searchForm.value));
    this.advertService.propertySearch(this.searchParams).subscribe(data => {
      this.properties = data;
      this.properties.forEach(property => {
        if (property.photos) {
          property.mainPhotoUrl =  property.photos['url'];
          console.log(property.mainPhotoUrl);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.properties);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for remove empty property `Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] == undefined || obj[key] == '' ? delete obj[key] : '');`

if only remove undefined property

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] == undefined ? delete obj[key] : '');
```

Your code update:

```
 var obj = Object.assign({}, this.searchForm.value);
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] == undefined || obj[key] == '' ? delete obj[key] : '');
this.searchParams = obj
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force excluded fields value like this: `Object.assign({}, this.searchForm.value, {town: undefined, selling_type: undefined})`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` and filter out what you don't need, then use `reduce` on them to build new object

```js
function filterObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value !== "").reduce((obj, entry) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

console.log(filterObject({a:1, b:false, c:'', d:'something'}));
```

or using `Object.fromEntries` (supported currently only on Chrome and Firefox)

```
function filterObject(obj) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value !== ""));
}
```